# Duplicate item in dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I was create a Employee registration page with dropdown list.Its used for selecting priority for each user. suppose i want to edit some user detail in this time am using the below code to select the dropdown list. It returns repeat value with out first index. That means a user have 3rd priority means it select third priority with out having 1st priority.

```
   foreach (DataRow dr in DS.Rows)
            {
                txtemail.Enabled = false;
                pan_addEdit.Visible = true;
                this.btnSave.Text = "Update";
                lbluserid.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["fdluserId"]);
                txtuername.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["flduser"]);
                txtPass.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["fldpass"]);
                txtemail.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["fldemail"]);
                ddlstatus.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(dr["fldstatus"]);
                ddlusergroup.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(dr["fldgroupId"]);
                ddldept.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(dr["flddept"]);
                ddlperiority.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(dr["fldperiority"]);
            }
```

dropdown show the below value after binding

```
   1st priority
   2nd priority
   3rd priority
```

dropdown show the below value after binding

```
  3rd priority
  2nd priority
  3rd priority
```

please help me to fix this error..

Comment: just make the **SelectedIndex** accordingly

Comment: am not saved that index value

Comment: what?? i didn't get it at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the FindByValue method to search the DropDownList for an Item with a Value matching the parameter.

```
ddlperiority.ClearSelection();
ddlperiority.Items.FindByValue(dr["fldperiority"].ToString()).Selected = true;
```

Alternatively you can use the FindByText method to search the DropDownList for an Item with Text matching the parameter.

Before using the FindByValue method, don't forget to reset the DropDownList so that no items are selected by using the ClearSelection() method. It clears out the list selection and sets the Selected property of all items to false. Otherwise you will get the following exception.

```
"Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList"
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to change the `Text` of the curently selected item. You want to change the selection itself. Therefor you could use the [`SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.selectedindex.aspx) or the [`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx) property of the DropdownList.

```
ddlperiority.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(dr["fldperiority"]);
```

Of course there must be a value that matches `dr["fldperiority"]`. Maybe this is the text field and you need the PK/FK field.

Answer (score 0):

Please do like below

```
 ddlstatus.Items.Clear();
 ddlperiority.Items.Clear();
 ddlusergroup.Items.Clear();
 ddldept.Items.Clear();
 foreach (DataRow dr in DS.Rows)
            {
                txtemail.Enabled = false;
                pan_addEdit.Visible = true;
                this.btnSave.Text = "Update";
                lbluserid.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["fdluserId"]);
                txtuername.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["flduser"]);
                txtPass.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["fldpass"]);
                txtemail.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["fldemail"]);
                ddlstatus.Items.Add ( Convert.ToString(dr["fldstatus"]));
                ddlusergroup.Items.Add( Convert.ToString(dr["fldgroupId"]));
                ddldept.Items.Add(  Convert.ToString(dr["flddept"]));
                ddlperiority.Items.Add(  Convert.ToString(dr["fldperiority"]));
            }
```

Comment: can you try my new answer above?

Comment: I need all the list of dropdown list if am using ur above code means it only return one value not all

Answer (score 0):

If still above answers are not working for you, try something like this

```
var item = Convert.ToString(dr["fldperiority"]);
    switch(item)       
          {         
             case "1st priority":   
                ddlperiority.SelectedIndex = 0;
                break;
             case "2nd priority":   
                ddlperiority.SelectedIndex = 1;
                break;
             case "3rd priority":   
                ddlperiority.SelectedIndex = 2;
                break;
           }
```

Comment: Dropdown list value is dynamic not static value .

Comment: Are you not setting the **datavalue field** and **datatextfield** ??